# gnuplot: scatter two data sets in a 3D plot

Tags: 3d, dataset, gnuplot, scatter-plot

I have two data sets: `data_1.dat` and `data_2.dat`:

```
 # data_1.dat
 1 1.1  2.1
 2 2.2  2.4
```

and:

```
 # data_2.dat
 1.5 1.4  2.3
 2.7 2.6  2.8
```

I would like to scatter plot both data sets, in the same 3D plot.

The following code only plots the last `splot` call, as shown in the Figure.

How could I also plot `data_1` in the same graph ?

```
 set termoption enhanced
 set ticslevel 0
 splot "data_1.dat" using 1:2:3 with points lc 2 ps 4 title "data 1"
 splot "data_2.dat" using 1:2:3 with points lc 3 title "data 2"
 pause -1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have both data sets in a single plot you must use a single `splot` call:

```
set style data points
splot "data_1.dat" u 1:2:3 lc 2 ps 4 title "data 1", "data_2.dat" u 1:2:3 lc 3 title "data 2"
```